# Compare object properties by keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to make a comparison of the object properties by key.
There are some sample data:

```
const data = [{
    "name": "John",
    "value": "30"
}, {
    "name": "Cindy",
    "value": "50"
}, {
    "name": "Mathew",
    "value": "80"
}, {
    "name": "Mike",
    "value": "35"
}];
```

so I would like to compare property values(value) of John and Mike names(key). If value of Mike is different than John than mutate value of Mike with value of John.
There is some algorithm

```
data.map(obj => {
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      let johnValue;
      let mikeValue;

      if(obj[key] == 'John') {
        johnValue = Number(obj.value)
      }
      else if(obj[key] == 'Mike') {
        mikeValue = Number(obj.value)
      }

      if(johnValue != mikeValue) {
        newData = {
          ...data,
          "Mike":  johnValue
        } 
      }
    }
  }
})
```

after whose execution I expected data like

```
const data = [{
        "name": "John",
        "value": "30"
    }, {
        "name": "Cindy",
        "value": "50"
    }, {
        "name": "Mathew",
        "value": "80"
    }, {
        "name": "Mike",
        "value": "30"
    }];
```

Is there a way to write it better using some of the ES6 features?
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwebster750/g1hsct0L/9/)

Comment: does it work? what do you get? please add the wanted result.

Comment: What is your preferred output, just `{ name: 'Mike', 'value': 35, 'Mike': 30 }` for the object that has a name of mike??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it a bit shorter

```
const MikeRecordInd = data.findIndex(v => v.name === 'Mike')
const JohnRecord = data.find(v => v.name === 'John')

if (data[MikeRecordInd].value !== JohnRecord.value) {
  newData = [...data]
  newData[MikeRecordInd] = { name: 'Mike', value: JohnRecord.value }
}
```